# Cannot find module './app/app.module.ngfactory' while install ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have received ag-grid enterprise trial licence key.

Then tried to install ag-grid enterprise as guide [Link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/#gsc.tab=0)

Installed by  `npm install ag-grid-enterprise --save-dev`

Here is my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


import {platformBrowser} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {AppModuleNgFactory} from "./app/app.module.ngfactory";  //<== Cannot find module './app/app.module.ngfactory' error

import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise/main";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("my trial licence key..");

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "commcodeviewer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "ag-grid": "^14.2.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^14.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"

 },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.56",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^15.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1"

 }
}
```

Actually, I don't have `app.module.ngfactory.ts`.
As for searching the internet, this seems being generated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you building with aot, then try building without aot.

Comment: can you provide your package.json ?

Comment: I added package.json.    I'm trying ot building witht aot, but it failed with same error message.